# Shortcut with WinEdt 8

Tags: winedt

How do I create a shortcut (say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for `\alpha`) with WinEdt 8? It used to be quite simple with WinEdt 5.5.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already a (double) shortcut in WinEdt 8 to insert `\alpha`.

It is <kbd>Alt+G</kbd> and then <kbd>A</kbd>.

If you want to create a single shortcut like <kbd>Alt+A</kbd> do the following steps:

Go to "Options" -> "Options Interface" and double-click the "Main Menu" item:

[image]

A local copy of `MainMenu.ini` gets opened. In this file, after the lines

```
MENU="Shortcuts"
  CAPTION="Shortcuts"
  INVISIBLE=1
```

add the following lines

```
  ITEM="$alpha"
    CAPTION="&alpha"
    MACRO="Ins('\alpha');"
    SHORTCUT="32833::Alt+A"
```

At this point press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

Now the shortcut <kbd>Alt+A</kbd> inserts `\alpha`