# Popup list of labels in WinEdt

Tags: labels, winedt

I am using WinEdt 7.0. In certain circumstances I would like to popup the window of labels. How can I do it without typing "\ref{}"?

If I would like to assign a shortcut to popping-up the window of labels, what is the corresponding macro or execution code?

I see that for active strings like `\?ref{?},,` there are macros like `Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Ref-sel.edt');]`. But such macros not only popup the window of labels but also do something else (e.g., move the cursor to one place left, delete certain words before the cursor). Is there an execution which only has the effect of popping-up the window of labels?

(In gather view I can see the list of labels, but I don't like that. I prefer the popping-up window to the gather view.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The macro you need is `%b\Macros\Active Strings\Ref.edt`, so a call

```
CharRight;Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Ref.edt');
```

will do what you need.

The simplest way to do that is "Macros" menu -> "Define and Run Macro" and type the above command.

To assign it a shortcut, see the instructions for example, in this answer of mine: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215416/27635.

Adapt it to your needs, just remember that in your case it must be

```
    MACRO="CharRight;Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Ref.edt');"
```

---

Alternatively, you can try with:

```
GlobalMark;GDIPopup('Label','Labels',1,1,0,1,0,'','',0,0,0,1,',');GlobalReturn;IfOK(!`Ins('%?');`);
```

which is an excerpt of `Ref.edt` which does exactly what you want without all the other things this macro does.

Comment: Isn't there a `View -> Gather…` menu in WinEdt7?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but he/she said "In gather view I can see the list of labels, but I don't like that. I prefer the popping-up window to the gather view"

Comment: @karlkoeller Thank you very much for your answer! But it seems that this macro moves the cursor one place left when popping-out the window. Is there a way not to move the cursor when the macro is triggered?

Comment: @ZhiyuanDing Oh, you're right, I forgot this... Simply add `CharRight;` as in the edited answer. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @ZhiyuanDing Does the answer meet your needs now?

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @ZhiyuanDing You're welcome :-)

Comment: Congratulations for your 100K!

Comment: @egreg very kind of you, thanks very much :-)